# Using the AWS SDK for .NET, how would we get a list of the filenames from the S3 bucket?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, sdk

I want to know if it is possible to get a list of the filenames from an S3 bucket using the AWS SDK for .NET. So far I can only get a count of how many buckets I have.

Comment: You should have tried searching AWS documentation on Google ;) example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingNetSDK.html   ListObjects documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_ListObjects.htm

Comment: Thanks! From the documentation. Is there anyway to put a filter on where it only list objects containing a certain word?

Comment: In the documentation, you see that ListObjectsRequest object is used. You can use Prefix field of the ListObjectsRequest to limit. As far as I know, you can only limit by prefix (so, starting with), not by "contains"

Answer (score 1):

It's true that the prefix parameter only specifies a pattern for the start of a name. There is a ListObjects example in GitHub as well: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/dotnetv3/S3/ListObjectsExample

To modify the example to return only keys that begin with "d", for example, this is the only change you would have to make (the listObjectsV2Paginator definition starts at line 38 of the example):

```
var listObjectsV2Paginator = client.Paginators.ListObjectsV2(new ListObjectsV2Request
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Prefix = "d",
});
```